# Loosing type, generic method

Tags: angular, typescript

Iam trying to create a generic method(for calling the backend) in a standard way.

Here is the problem, I pass in a special `type`(here `Recipe`):

```
let a = this._adminService.Generic_(this.UI_Recipes[0], ECRUD.Create, EProductType.Recipe);
```

And I want to read that class-name(`type`) on the other side:

```
Generic_<T>(arg: T, method: ECRUD, producttype: EProductType): T {
//...
call = this.baseUrl + product + arg.constructor.name; // => "Object"
//...
```

I see in the debugger `arg`, now as `typ`: `Object`.
He is loosing the `typ`, after entering `Generic_`-method. See [here](https://ibb.co/PjfkPqF).

What can I do here ?

`typeof arg` => "object"

Comment: There's a difference between TypeScript types and JavaSript types. TypeScript types get lost at runtime

Comment: @CristianTraìna is there no chance to make a generic method, (because I see so much redundant code(, starting at the Fronend => Backend Controller => Business Layer ...)) ?

Comment: ````Generic_<T extends EProductType>(constructor:{new (...args: any[]):T}, yourArgList...):T{...}````

Comment: @BálintRéthy can you provide an example, how to access that method ?(do I need a write a method signature for every type ?)

Answer (score 0):

The requested example:

```
class ScriptPosition{
  line:number;
  path:string;
  time:string;

  constructor(time:string, line:number, path?:string){
    this.time = time;
    this.line = line;
    this.path = path || null;
  }
}

class _Command extends ScriptPosition{

  constructor(time:string, line:number, path?:string){
    super(time, line, path);
  }
}

class _Step extends ScriptPosition{

  constructor(time:string, line:number, path?:string){
    super(time, line, path);
  }
} //and so on
```

```
@Component({...})
export class ScriptLogComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   ...
   ngOnInit(){
     this.setLogPath<_Command>(_Command);
     setTimeout(() => {
       this.setLogPath<_Step>(_Step, 1550);
     }, 10000);
   }

   setLogPath<T extends ScriptPosition>(constructor:{new (...args: any[]):T}, scriptPosition?:T){
     ///Do something with scriptPosition or call another function like this:
     scriptPosition = scriptPosition || this._getScriptPositionTypeFromLineIndex<T>(this.actualLineIndex, constructor);
   }

   private _getScriptPositionTypeFromLineIndex<T extends ScriptPosition>(index:number, constructor:{new (...args: any[]):T}):T{...}
   ...
}
```

This is just an example about how to work with generic functions in TypeScript.

Hope it helps ^^